# IntelliJ IDEA - disable (re-)fomat code as you type

Tags: intellij-idea

I think IDEA didn't do that before, but after some recent upgrade, I find this behavior: as I type some code around some lines which are not well-formatted, IDEA re-formats those as well.

Super-simplified example: having this code:

```
MyThing aThing = new MyThing(){};
```

When I add an `if` around it, the moment I close the curly brace, it re-formats the code to:

```
if (condition) {
  MyThing a = new MyThing()   // IDEA added new line here!
  {                           // and here!
  };                          // and here!
}
```

and I have to go and remove those new lines manually again...

This feature is maybe a good thing in a general case, but I don't like it being applied everywhere - first, I probably want to include a small fix and don't want my change to appear bigger than it is; and second, more importantly, there are cases where the code deliberately doesn't comply with otherwise common code style, like above - just because it is simpler that way and not the other.

In the end - I would like to disable this feature, and only re-format code when executed explicitly, like with `Ctrl-Alt-L`, but keep all code as-is otherwise. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an option to disable automatic identation of block when typing `}`.

At the `File` menu, go to `Settings...` and search for `reformat`. Choose `Smart Keys` under `Editor > General` and you will see highlighted the option `Reformat block on typing '}'` - uncheck it, save the settings and you are done.

This setting is also available in Android Studio, which is powered from IntelliJ.

[image]